# Programatically adding to Messenger context menu Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I was wondering if anyone has any experience or knows if there is any way to add options to a system context menu in a windows phone 8.1 built in app. Specifically, I would like if possible to add a "copy to" option that copies data directly from a message to my app instead of having to select

```
-> copy to clipboard -> find my app -> paste into application.
```

Is this possible? Is there any other technique I could leverage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can make your app a share target to accept data shared from apps which do so, but that won't help for your specific case since the Messaging app doesn't share its messages.